# What's the best way to grep in more files for a line that starts with a sign

Tags: grep

I organize all my text notes in AsciiDoc files. AsciiDoc is a file format similar to Markdown but instead of `#` I use `=` to denote a first level-heading, like so:

first-file.adoc

```
= How To Install MySQL 8.0 on Fedora
```

second-file.adoc

```
= Summaries and Notes From Books I've Read
```

Knowing that each file include one and "only one" first-level heading `= This is a First-Level Heading` and it is always on line number 1,
my goal is to search through all files using `grep` and only look in those first-level headings.

This grep command matches the second file:

```
grep -in '^= .*ooks' *.adoc
```

It makes sense and it is what I need. However my terminal highlight with red everything up until the word "Books" and leaves the rest "I've Read" with white. Is that normal?

**= Summaries and Notes From Books** I've Read

Comment: ... or, to put it another way, spaces are literal in a grep regex. So `.* rst` would match `fi rst` but never `first`

Comment: @Archemardo you mean something like this: `grep '^= ' *.adoc | grep -in 'rst'` it seems to work.

Comment: @archemer and steeldriver make an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep solution

## search

```
grep '^=.*rst.*$' *.adoc
```

where

- `^` begin of line
- `=` equal
- `.*` anything any number of time
- `rst` string rst
- `.*` anything any number of time
- `$` end of line

this will list files and found line

```
first.adoc:= The title of the first file
```

## print result

grep will highlight what part of line triggered the match, so

```
grep '^=.*rst' *.adoc
```

will highlight

first.adoc:**= The title of the first** file

because search to end-of-line wasn't requested.

```
grep '^=.*rst.*$' *.adoc
```

will highlight

first.adoc:**= The title of the first file**

because search to end-of-line was requested.

to only files use `-l` ( or `--file-with-matches`)

```
grep -l '^=.*rst' *.adoc
```

to only list lines and not the filename use `-h` (or `--no-filename`)

see `man grep`

Comment: Thanks. I need the file name. Your solution works, but the output highlights only the words up to "first", those are shown with red color and the word "file" remains white, even though the output is what I was looking for. There is a space after the equal sign. `grep -in '^= .*rst' *.adoc`

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me. What would be the correct way to represent a space in regexp? I have a space after the equal sign like so `= Title`. I've tried something like this: `grep -in '^=\s.*rst.*$' *.adoc`  where `\s` represents a space. Or should I just add a space with the spacebar `^= .*rst.*$'`

Comment: just use `^= ` (begining of line, equal, space (not a tab)) or else `^=[:blank:]`

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `awk`, GNU version that supports `nextfile`, all you need to do is

```
awk '{ if ( $0 ~ /fifth/ ) print FILENAME  ; nextfile }' *.adoc
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like the whole title to be highlighted.

If that's the case, you just need to add .* to the end of your expresion. grep shows you in red the past of the line that matches your matching expression.

Comment: They don't say whether they want the output highlighted or not. They only wonder if it's normal to have the output partially highlighted.  As far as I know, it's only GNU `grep` that does this sort of highligting.